# C# converts inches to cents

Tags: c#

This method converts inches to centimeter. `1 = 2.54 cm`.

Now i'm using in method void type, but can it be done with double type?
can someone show me this code in double type.

```
namespace csharpnoobie
{
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
      Console.Write("give number in inches : ");
      int calculating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      inches(calculating);
      Console.ReadKey();
      }

      private static void inches(int calculating)
      {

      Console.WriteLine(calculating + " inches = " + 2.54 * calculating + " cm");
      return;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Is `cents` really a widely understood abbreviation of `centimeter`? (I'm not a native speaker of English, so this is an honest question.)

Comment: This is the third question I've seen you post in the last three days where you don't even attempt it yourself. As somebody said on the last question, if you want to learn C#, attempt it, and if it doesn't work THEN ask for help. You are just asking everyone else to solve your problems.

Comment: @Heinzi - No, it's not. The abbreviation for centimetres is cm. Cents are a unit of currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
class Program : MarshalByRefObject
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("give number in inches : ");
        int calculating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        inches(calculating);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static double inches(int calculating)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(calculating + " inches = " + 2.54 * calculating + " cm");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think returning 0 is quite what the OP wanted

Comment: Why does your program inherit from MarshalByRefObject?

Comment: @csahrpnoobie why? Returning 0 is useless and at worst, ambigious and confusing. If you call a method called 'inches' that returns a double I sure as hell expect that method to return the conversion, not 0

Comment: @csahrpnoobie, ROFL. That's was an irony. You may revoke your upvote since my answer absolutely useless.

Comment: @RichK: You're absolutely right. -1 on the question (not the answer) for making no sense at all.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy Phew, I was getting a little bit worried there. I almost want to upvote just for the audacity of it now...

Comment: @Heinzi, because it's code template for `Windows Console Application` project.

Answer (score 5):

```
public double ConvertCentimetersToInches(int centimeters)
{
   return centimeters / 2.54;
}
```

Comment: -1 That will convert inches to cents (sic - centimetres), and not cents to inches.

Comment: oh dear, I need to reboot with a strong coffee :-(

Comment: The OP wants something which converts inches to centimeters